# ¿Por que me marca este error en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

> Notice
> : Undefined variable: listaProductos in
> C:\xampp8\htdocs\fast\index.php
> on line
> 53

Este es el código:

```
<?php
    $sentencia=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblproductos`");
    $sentencia->execute();
    $listaProductos=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($listaProductos);
   
    ?>
```

La línea 53 es la de `print_r`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `53` del archivo `index.php` que se encuentra en esta ruta: **C:\xampp8\htdocs\fast\?** No puede ser el código que muestras aquí, porque el mismo no debería tener ese error.

Comment: la linea 53 de mi codigo index.php es la de print_r($listaProductos);

Comment: por eso no entiendo porque me marca error, ya lo volvi a escribir de nuevo, lo cargue y actualice y sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: Limpia la caché del navegador. No puede ocurrir ese error en ese código.